# computeFunction must not be nil error reported

Tags: ios, macos, metal

The error that ComputeFunction must not be nill was reported after a metal shading function has been called repeatedly for about 248 times.

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-56.6/Framework/MTLComputePipeline.mm:230: failed assertion `computeFunction must not be nil.'
Abort trap: 6
```

The first 247 calls worked correctly, but the program failed at the 248th call.
What causes this and how can it be avoided? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only the command buffer and encoder are transient and can be created on every call (inside the `draw()` function). libraries/functions are not transient so you should avoid creating them repeatedly.